# Sharing data between multiple map() and reduce() calls

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I need a HashMap object to be shared between map() and reduce().

Explanation:
I want the map() to retrieve and update some data in the HashMap for its current key.
I want the reduce() to then be able to see if the current key has the maximum value when compared to past key-values.

And on the last key-value pair(I plan to use HashMap.size() and a static integer counter for this), I will print the key-value pair with the maximum value.

So basically I need a HashMap object shared between map() and reduce(), and then an integer variable shared between the reduce() calls.

Any Help?

Comment: Can you give an example of data and what processing you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this program by changing my approach. In the mapper, I simply transformed/processed each K,V pair that I got. Then I passed all of that to the reducer, where I could use static variable in the Class' scope, as there is only one reducer node. Plus I learned about cleanup function too.

In-short I had this problem because I hadn't understood Map, Reduce and their applications properly.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how mapreduce is intended to be used... If you create any Hashmap in the mapper, there would be one hashmap per mapper, and there can be thousands of map tasks each running at the same time. Any of the reducer tasks would not know which Hashmap to check against and there's no explicit step for you to consolidate them

Perhaps it would be better to externalize that data into Redis, for example

Comment: Not to Worry, I managed this program by changing my approach.
In the mapper, I simply transformed/processed each K,V pair that I got.
Then I passed all of that to the reducer, where I could use static variable in the Class' scope, as there is only one reducer node.
Plus I learned about cleanup function too.